# How to handle <a href> inside a button in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I am using wordpress for this project. How can I handle the `<a>` tag which is getting displayed inside a button?
Here is how I am using it

```
 <button class="red-btn btn-effect reply" type="button">
        <?php comment_reply_link(array_merge( $args, array('depth' => $depth, 'max_depth' => $args['max_depth']))) ?>
    </button>
```

and its output is shown as

```
<button class="red-btn btn-effect reply">
        <a rel="nofollow" class="comment-reply-link" href="http://localhost/dynamoLogic/security-vulnerabilities-in-php/?replytocom=3#respond" onclick="return addComment.moveForm( &quot;comment-3&quot;, &quot;3&quot;, &quot;respond&quot;, &quot;18&quot; )" aria-label="Reply to umair">Reply</a>        </button>
```

Html5 does not support `<a>` tags inside a button. How to handle this?

Comment: Is there any reason for using a button? `<a></a>` with proper styling should be enough. Take the class attribute values on the `<button></button>` element and add to the `<a></a>` and you should be fine then remove the button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is because a button is not a link.

Remove the button and your output should actually be something like this instead:

```
<a rel="nofollow" class="red-btn btn-effect reply comment-reply-link" href="http://localhost
/dynamoLogic/security-vulnerabilities-in-php/?replytocom=3#respond" 
onclick="return addComment.moveForm( &quot;comment-3&quot;, &quot;3&quot;,
&quot;respond&quot;, &quot;18&quot; )" aria-label="Reply to 
umair">Reply</a>
```

Add in the neccessary classes for the link, you may need to make adjustments to the CSS for the a element.